# Clean MATLAB time series data

Tags: matlab, time-series

I have a Matlab time series data set, which consist of a signal that can only be 1 or 0. How can I get rid of all the values except for the changing ones?
For example:

```
1
1
1
0
1
0
0
0
```

should ideally result in

```
1
0
1
0
```

while keeping the correct time values as well of course.
Thing is, that I need to find the frequency of the signal. The time should be measured from 0->1 to the next time 0->1 occurs. The smallest time / highest frequency is what I need in the end.

Thanks!

Comment: When reading your question I assumed you have a `timeseries` object, the other two answers assume your input data is a vector. What is right?

Comment: You are right. I am getting a timeseries object out of a simulink simulation. I tried to use the diff methods described below by you guys but so far couldn't get it to work. I'll try the getsamples method next :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `getsamples` method to get a time series which contains a subset of the original samples. Remains to identify the indices where the time series has changed, for this purpose you can use `diff` and logical indexing:

```
ts = timeseries([1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0],1:8)
ts.getsamples([true;squeeze(diff(ts.Data)) ~= 0])
```

Comment: Your solution almost works for me!
I had to change your code to:
ts_short = getsamples(ts, squeeze(diff(ts.Data)) ~= 0);
Then it works except for the very first change in the data set, which I think happens because the first points of the array are all the same?

Comment: @Jonnnny What was wrong with my solution? Then I can maybe understand what you need.

Comment: Okay I only missed the need for the 'true'. Works perfectly now. Thanks!
With your solution the resulting array stayed exactly the same size as the original for me. No idea why ;-)

Comment: You need the true because the first element should always be part of the resulting timeseries, and all following elements only if their difference to the previous in unequal to zero.

Answer (score 3):

A simple and clever call to to [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) should be sufficient:

```
>> A = [1; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0];
>> B = A(diff([-Inf; A]) ~= 0)

B =

     1
     0
     1
     0
```

The code is quite simple.  `diff` finds pairs of differences in an array.  Concretely, given an array `A`, the output is of the following structure:

```
B = [A(2) - A(1), A(3) - A(2), ..., A(N) - A(N-1)];
```

`N` is the total length of the signal.  This results in a `N-1` length signal.  As such, a trick that you can use is to append the array `A` with `-Inf` (or some high non-zero value) so that when you find the difference between the first element of this appended array and the actual first element of the true array, you will get some non-zero change.  That is registered with `diff([-Inf; A])`.  The next thing you'll want is to check is to see where the differences are **non-zero**.  Whenever there is a non-zero difference, that is a position that you want to keep because there has been a change that occurred.  This produces a `logical` array and so the last step is to use this to index into your array `A` and thus get the result.

---

This only extracts out the signal you need however.  If you'd like to extract the time in between unique elements, supposing you had some time vector `t` that was as long as your signal stored in `A`.  You would first record the logical vector in a separate variable, then index into both your time array and the signal array to extract out what you need (original idea from user dfri):

```
ind = diff([-Inf; A]) ~= 0;
times = t(ind);
B = A(ind);
```

Comment: If you want the first element to be true, why not simply use `B = A([true; diff(A) ~= 0])`? Both is fully correct for this application, but I think this way it's simpler to understand and explain.

Comment: @Daniel That's actually a very good point, but that would mean that it would be similar to user dfri's answer.  I'll leave this the way it is to show uniqueness.  Thank you for your suggestion nonetheless!

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `diff` and `logical` to save the results as a logical array, used as a subsequent index filter in your data (say `t` for time and `y` for boolean values ))

```
%// example
t = 0:0.01:0.07;
y = [1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0];

%// find indices to keep
keep = [true logical(diff(y))];

%// truncated data
tTrunc = t(keep)
yTrunc = y(keep)
```

with the results for the example as follows

```
tTrunc =

     0     0.0300    0.0400    0.0500


yTrunc =

     1     0     1     0
```

Comment: That's another nice way to use `diff` as well. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng It would seem from our answers as `diff` is the way to go, but you slightly beat me to it, +1! (or, as Daniel added, `getsamples` :) )

Comment: Returns wrong results when the first element is 0. `keep = [true logical(diff(y))];`